# npm run build gives out npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, package.json

I'm very new to Node.js and Electron and wanted to run `npm run build`. Unfortunately, that only gives me out the error code ELIFECYCLE.

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
    "name": "firstelectronproject",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "My first Electron project",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron index.js",
        "package": "",
        "build": "electron-packager . FEP"
    },
    "author": "F9lke <florian.thomasgoetzrath.de>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "electron": "^1.6.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "asar": "^0.13.0",
        "electron-packager": "^8.7.2"
    }
}
```

Here is the log of my command prompt:

```
 D:\Eigene Dateien\Desktop\Coding\Desktop Apps\FEP>npm run build

> firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build D:\Eigene Dateien\Desktop\Coding\Desktop Apps\FEP
> electron-packager . FEP

Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v1.6.11
Command failed: npm prune --production
npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
npm WARN firstelectronproject@0.1.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! May not delete: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\FEP-win32-x64\resources\app\node_modules\.bin

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-21T11_38_37_230Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build: `electron-packager . FEP`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-21T11_38_37_293Z-debug.log
```

And here is the log output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v6.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~prebuild: firstelectronproject@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: firstelectronproject@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\Eigene Dateien\Desktop\Coding\Desktop Apps\FEP\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: CWD: D:\Eigene Dateien\Desktop\Coding\Desktop Apps\FEP
10 silly lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron-packager . FEP' ]
11 silly lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle firstelectronproject@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build: `electron-packager . FEP`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
14 verbose pkgid firstelectronproject@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Eigene Dateien\Desktop\Coding\Desktop Apps\FEP
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v6.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build: `electron-packager . FEP`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the firstelectronproject@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your project? Trying to reproduce on my machine and it would be great if I could get the complete project.

Comment: Please try .\node_modules\.bin\eslint (the path separator is \ on Windows) or yarn add eslint-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing the array `unique` and it started working:

```
npm install --save array-unique
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to a bug in `electron-packager`. As a workaround you could downgrade `electron-packager` to e.g. `^7.7.0`. Also, you need to update the `build` command slightly, see below (Note, only showing the relevant parts):

```
{
  "scripts": {                                                 
    "build": "electron-packager ./ --platform=linux --arch=x64"
  },                                                           
  "dependencies": {                                            
    "electron": "^1.6.11"                                      
  },                                                           
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^7.7.0"                              
  }                                                            
}
```

Note that you can use `--all` to build for all platforms.

Comment: So it would be "--platform=--all" for all platforms? Thank you so much!

Comment: Nope, just `--all` I think

Answer (score 2):

Updating npm on server worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with electron-packager. Just added `./ --all` to the end of the pack directive. Final result given below:

```
"pack": "electron-packager ./ --all"
```